# How the initial palindrome length at index i equal to R - i in "Manacher's algorithm"?

Tags: algorithm, substring, palindrome

I am learning the Manacher's algorithm to solve the Longest Palindromic Substring problem and I understand that it leverages the fact that if i' is centre of palindrome then there will be a palindrome centred at i.

Instead of expanding from zero , we maintain a array P to keep track of len of palindromes centre at i as we go.
My question is how do we know the there will be palindrome of size R-i if palindrom at mirror is smaller?

This is the code for it.

```py
    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
        # Transform S into T.
        # For example, S = "abba", T = "^#a#b#b#a#$".
        # ^ and $ signs are sentinels appended to each end to avoid bounds checking
        T = '#'.join('^{}$'.format(s))
        n = len(T)
        P = [0] * n
        C = R = 0
        for i in range (1, n-1):

            if (R > i):
               # WHY R-i, how do we know there will be palindrome of size R -i
                P[i] =  min(R - i, P[2*C - i]) 

            # Attempt to expand palindrome centered at i
            while T[i + 1 + P[i]] == T[i - 1 - P[i]]:
                P[i] += 1

            # If palindrome centered at i expand past R,
            # adjust center based on expanded palindrome.
            if i + P[i] > R:
                C, R = i, i + P[i]

        # Find the maximum element in P.
        maxLen, centerIndex = max((n, i) for i, n in enumerate(P))    
        return s[(centerIndex  - maxLen)//2: (centerIndex  + maxLen)//2]
```

all the example that that I found are like

```
a # b # a # b # b # a # b # a
   i'          C         i
```

I understand that in this case there are subpalindromes at i, but what about cases like

```
a # b # c # d # d # c # b # a
   i'          C         i
```

How do we know P[i] will either be R-i or Palindrome at mirror ?

Answer (score 0):

This page explains manacher's algorithm and answers the question with visual animations.

[Visual explaination of Manacher's algorithm](https://tarokuriyama.com/projects/palindrome2.php)